# In which file I can find the changes this command made? "usermod -aG sudo user_name"

Tags: linux, sudo

I just add new user to the sudo group. I thought I can find every user that is in sudoers group in sudoers file. But I can't find it there.

Please, where I can see some "output" of this command? Where I can check e.g. in nano that new user has been added in sudoers group?

Thank you!

Comment: `/etc/group` will contain the changes. (e.g. `grep 'sudo' /etc/group`)

Comment: Thanks a lot! my next question is for what there is a file sudoers?

Comment: The `sudoers` file is `/etc/sudoers`. But **DO NOT** edit that file directly. Use `visudo` to modify it. You of course can look at it (e.g. `# cat /etc/sudoers`) and read the comments, but only edit it with `visudo`